# Symfony2: manual file upload with VichUploaderBundle

Tags: php, symfony, vichuploaderbundle

How can I upload file with [VichUploaderBundle](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle) without form?

I have file in some directory (for example `web/media/tmp/temp_file.jpg`)

If I try this:

```
$file = new UploadedFile($path, $filename);

$image = new Image();
$image->setImageFile($file);

$em->persist($image);
$em->flush();
```

I've got this error:

> The file "temp_file.jpg" was not uploaded due to an unknown error.

I need to upload file from remote url. So I upload file to `tmp` direcotry (with curl) and then I keep trying to inject it to VichUploadBundle (as you can see above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: `VichUploaderBundle` does not support uploading files without using Symfony Form component.

> I need to upload file from remote url. So I upload file to tmp direcotry (with curl) and then I keep trying to inject it to VichUploadBundle (as you can see above).

In that case, you don't need to upload, you need to download. And that's not what `VichUploaderBundle` is meant to do.

Comment: Oh, I was afraid of this. But it doesn't matter, I will figure out something else. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 11):

Accepted answer is not correct (anymore?). According with the [usage documentation](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/usage.md) 
you can indeed manually upload a `File` without using Symfony's Form Component:

```
/**
 * If manually uploading a file (i.e. not using Symfony Form) ensure an instance
 * of 'UploadedFile' is injected into this setter to trigger the  update. If this
 * bundle's configuration parameter 'inject_on_load' is set to 'true' this setter
 * must be able to accept an instance of 'File' as the bundle will inject one here
 * during Doctrine hydration.
 *
 * @param File|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile $image
 */
public function setImageFile(File $image = null)
{
    $this->imageFile = $image;

    if ($image) {
        // It is required that at least one field changes if you are using doctrine
        // otherwise the event listeners won't be called and the file is lost
        $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime('now');
    }
}
```

Comment: `UploadedFile` object must have test flag set to true if you want to "upload" a local stored file, e.g.: migrating files from a local dir to VichUploader configured upload_destination

Comment: how do you upload the file? When I do SetImageFile, the DB gets filed but the file never is uploader to my destination folder (on S3). Thx

Answer (score 4):

You should use `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile` instead of `File`:

```
$file = new UploadedFile($filename, $filename, null, filesize($filename), false, true);
```

`VichUploaderBundle` will handle this object.

Comment: For completeness it would be better update your answer explaining the code and/or preferably with adding a link pointing to the relative documentation on github if it exist (or make a PR if not).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, but as @gp_sflover pointed out, it should be edited to further explain how it works: the last parameter (set mode test = true) allows using UploadedFile without actually uploading a file, since the file is already on the server.

Answer (score 3):

To combine the answers and address an issue with VichUploader and `inject_on_load: true` changing the `updatedAt` during the `postLoad` event.

### Explanation of the issue

Since the VichUploader mapped property is not monitored by Doctrine ORM, you will need to ensure at least one of the properties that the ORM manages is changed to trigger the `prePersist` or `preUpdate` events that VichUploader uses to manage the file reference.
This is generally done by using an `updatedAt` DATETIME column in your file setter but can be any property that is managed by the ORM.

### `postLoad` event setter `File` instance issue

Verifying an instance of `UploadedFile` is supplied to the mapped property setter method, will ensure that `updatedAt` is changed *only* during Form submissions or when manually supplied, instead of during the `postLoad` event - where VichUpload supplies an instance of `File` to the same mapped setter method. Which would otherwise cause the `updatedAt` value in your views to change and potentially change the database value if you call `$em::flush()` when instances of the `Image` object are loaded by Doctrine and therefor managed.

***App\Entity\Image***

```php
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 */
class Image
{

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     * @ORM\Column(name="updated_at", type="datetime")
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    /**
     * @var \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="your_mapping", fileNameProperty="image")
     */
    private $imageFile;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     * @ORM\Column(name="image", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $image;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime('now');
    }

    //...

    public function setImageFile(File $image = null)
    {
        $this->imageFile = $image;
        if ($image instanceof UploadedFile) {
            $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime('now');
        }
    }

}
```

---

Then you can manually define the file to use in your entity by instantiating an `UploadedFile` object and setting the `error` argument as `null` and the `test` argument to `true`, which disables validating `UPLOAD_ERR_OK` and `is_uploaded_file()` [[sic]](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5.x/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.php#L165).

***Symfony <= 4.0***

```php
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

$file = new UploadedFile($path, $filename, null, filesize($path), null, true);
```

***Symfony 4.1+***

In Symfony 4.1 and later, the file size argument was deprecated.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

$file = new UploadedFile($path, $filename, null, null, true);
```

---

Now you can successfully persist and/or flush your entity with the manually uploaded file.

```
$image = new Image();
$image->setImageFile($file);

$em->persist($image);
$em->flush();
```